# Как убрать пробел после последней цифры, при построении числовой пирамиды?

Tags: c++, циклы, вывод

Написал код для создания числовой пирамиды на N строк,
где в каждой строке нумерация идет от 1 до N строки через пробел.
Все компилируется и работает, но нужно избавиться от последнего пробела(от пробела после последней цифры "ступеньки" пирамиды).
Подскажите, пожалуйста, что можно сделать.

```
for (int i = 0; i <= num; ++i)
{
    for (int j = 1; j <= i; ++j)
    {
        std::cout << j << " ";

    }

    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Если это так важно - например,

```
std::cout << j << (j != i ? " " : "");
```

Можно, конечно, и так -

```
std::cout << '\b' << std::endl;
```

но при перенаправлении вывода в файл там будет и пробел, и забой...

Comment: Можно ж просто отдельно вывести ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = 1; i <= num; ++i)
{
  for (int j = 1; j < i; ++j)
    std::cout << j << " ";

  std::cout << i << std::endl;
}
```